# NullPointerException when saving into a database

Tags: java, android, database, nullpointerexception

Im trying to save Strings that are: category, title, body into a database, however I'm getting a NullPointerException whenever I try to execute `saveState()` method. Could anyone help me ?

```
//exectued when I press Save button
public void onClickSave(View v) {
    saveState();
}

// fire up creation

private void saveState() {
    String title = mJokeTitle.getText().toString();
    String body = mJokeBody.getText().toString();

    long id = mDbHelper.createJoke(enteredCat, title, body);

}
```

my database schema

```
public class NotesDbAdapter {

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "category";

public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";

private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "my_database";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "jokes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "title text not null, body text not null, category text not null unique);";

public long createJoke(String category, String title, String body) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    // return rowId if successful, otherwise -1
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

Comment: most likely `mDbHelper` or `mDb` is `null`.

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: You should see it in the stacktrace where the `NullPointerException` was thrown.

Comment: did you create the `database` by extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` ?

Comment: @OschtärEi  thank you, that was the case !!

Comment: It may possible mJokeTitle or mJokeBody is null , I mean dont you forget to findViewByID() this edtitext/textview?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void saveState() {
    String title ="";
    String body="";
   if(mJokeTitle.getText()!=nll){
      title = mJokeTitle.getText().toString();
   }else{
       System.out.println("mJokeTitle.getText() value is null you need to look into  why this value is Null");  
   }

   if( mJokeBody.getText()!=nll){
      body = mJokeBody.getText().toString();
   }else{
       System.out.println(" mJokeBody.getText() value is null you need to look into why this value is Null");  
   }       
    if(mDbHelper!=null){
        long id = mDbHelper.createJoke(enteredCat, title, body);
    }else{
            System.out.println("mDbHelper value is null you need to look into why this value is Null");  
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more code, with the code provided the variable 'mDbHelper' within your saveState() Method is not initialized. If it is there is a second variable 'enteredCat' that we cant know if its initialised or not.

Answer (score 0):

mDbHelper was null that was the case